# Can "doing someone" mean "mimicking someone"?

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

Can *"do someone"* be us to mean *mimic* in expressions like *"Stop doing me!"* or *"He is doing Lisa"*? Or does it necessarily mean *having a sexual relationship with someone*?

Comment: Surely any dictionary would answer this, no?

Comment: I've seen it in the friends series S01E22 when Phoebe tells Chandler that his personnel mimick him.

Answer (score 4):

In context, it's perfectly fine.

I've seen people (mostly celebrities) who are good at impersonations interviewed. They'll speak like someone else, and the host will say something like, "Oh, do Marlon Brando now!" It's clear that this is a request for a Marlon Brando impersonation.

If you were to say, "Stop doing me!" I would assume it would be in response to me obviously trying to impersonate you. So, it would not be misunderstood.

But if you suddenly blurted out, "He is doing Lisa," and there wasn't any context for it, it would more commonly be taken to have a sexual connotation.

Comment: I'd say that the 'defrauding' sense is still the most common here, in the UK. But as you say, context is vital.

Answer (score 1):

When ever someone would tell me that he is "doing someone", I think that the definition of having a "sexual relationship" with that someone, is what would first come to mind.

It would be more appropriate to say that you are mimicking / imitating that poor Lisa, to convey your meaning.